# Kotlin: Subscribe to Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) Topic

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've used the Android (Java) way of doing things before for subscribing to a topic

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather")...
```

But was looking at the Kotlin [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#kotlin+ktx)

```
Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic("weather")...
```

I'm not finding how to get this class to show to be able to write it like the above.

I can get the Java way to show but not the Kotlin.

Anyone know what needs to be added to the Gradle or other to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess it that you forgot to add the Kotlin extensions, which means you only get the Java-level APIs.

To make the Kotlin extensions available, add the `-ktx` dependency to your Gradle file as shown in the documentation on [setting up Kotlin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#kotlin+ktx).

Comment: Wow! So right. Thx.